# How to show specific luns from lsscsi command?

Tags: linux, grep, awk

I need to grep specific `luns` from the `lsscsi` command.

For example:

```
[root@e15l1 ~]# lsscsi 4 0 1 | awk '{print $1,$6}' | head
[4:0:1:0] -
[4:0:1:1] /dev/sdab
[4:0:1:2] /dev/sdj
[4:0:1:3] /dev/sdz
[4:0:1:4] /dev/sdk
[4:0:1:12] /dev/sdo
[4:0:1:13] /dev/sdp
[4:0:1:38] /dev/sdad
```

How can I grep only `luns` 1, 12 and 13?

I am using:`lsscsi | awk '{ print $1,$6 }' | grep -w 4:0:1 | egrep -w '1|1[2-3]'`

The problem is when I am searching for a `lun` with same number as other `scsi` entries. For example in my case searching `lun` 1 will give the whole output because my `ID` is also 1. Same with `lun` 4(due `Host adapter`)...

Output should be as in the example, `scsi` entries and `/dev/...`

Comment: As I understand I need to use `-F` option to parse the number between ":" and "]"(`lun` number) and then do `grep`. But couldn't find the right command

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
lsscsi 4 0 1 | sed -r '/\[4:0:1:(1|12|13)\].*/!d'
```

Output will be:

```
[4:0:1:1] /dev/sdab
[4:0:1:12] /dev/sdo
[4:0:1:13] /dev/sdp
```

Comment: Thanks, worked as expected. Can I give a range this way? 

For example: if I want to search 20-28 `luns`, so I will not write each number?

Comment: @igor, yes. It will be something like this: `sed -r '/\[4:0:1:2[0-8]\].*/!d'`

Answer (score 2):

This should work I irrespective of the other numbers anywhere in the line  :

```
egrep '^\[\d+:\d+:\d+:(1|12|13)\]'
```

Might need also to backslash colons, not at the computer atm to check.

For doing it for a range substitute (1|2|13) for eg (2[0-8])